# Angularjs capture custom directive data back to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am facing a issue while getting the data from custom directive back to controller, I have different charts with data in each custom directive, all i want is to get each chart data in an object and push it to the array which is controller, [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/jP24KWTsJ15dDuifszm9?p=preview). Three objects are pushing in to array as expected but there is a nested array pushed-in each time charts data object push. I know there is an array declared for pushing each chart data, is this the correct approach? any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to pass in a function from the parent controller into the directive that updates the Array. Your implementation is causing issues by updating the Array that is being watched.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.sampleObject = [{
    name: "Graph1",
    key: "Graph1"
  }, {
    name: "Graph2",
    key: "Graph2"
  }, {
    name: "Graph3",
    key: "Graph3"
  }, ];

  $scope.captureData = [];
  $scope.doPushData = function(newData) {

    $scope.captureData.push(newData);
    console.log($scope.captureData);
  }
  /* 
  $scope.$watch('captureData',function(newValue){
    $scope.captureData.push(newValue);
    console.log($scope.captureData);
  });
  */
});

app.directive('myGraph', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      'graphName': '=',
      'pushData': '='
    },
    template: '<div class="lineChart">{{graphName}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var d3 = $window.d3;

      // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
      scope.margin = {
          top: 30,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 50
        },
        scope.width = 600 - scope.margin.left - scope.margin.right,
        scope.height = 270 - scope.margin.top - scope.margin.bottom;

      var svg = d3.select(".lineChart")
        .append("svg").attr("width", scope.width + scope.margin.left + scope.margin.right)
        .attr("height", scope.height + scope.margin.top + scope.margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + scope.margin.left + "," + scope.margin.top + ")");

      var data = [
        [
          1498102680000,
          6.9
        ],
        [
          1498102710000,
          4.5
        ],
        [
          1498102740000,
          8.4
        ],
        [
          1498102770000,
          4.8
        ],
        [
          1498102800000,
          9.7
        ],
        [
          1498102830000,
          9.6000000000000014
        ],
        [
          1498102860000,
          11.9
        ],
        [
          1498102890000,
          7.1000000000000005
        ],
        [
          1498102920000,
          8.0
        ],
        [
          1498102950000,
          6.2
        ],
        [
          1498102980000,
          5.6
        ],
        [
          1498103010000,
          6.6000000000000005
        ]
      ];

      // Parse the date / time
      var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

      // Set the ranges
      scope.xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, scope.width]);
      scope.yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([scope.height, 0]);

      // Define the axes
      scope.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scope.xScale)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

      scope.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scope.yScale)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

      // Define the line
      scope.valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return scope.xScale(d[0]);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return scope.yScale(d[1]);
        });

      // Scale the range of the data
      scope.xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d[0];
      }));
      scope.yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })]);

      // Add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", scope.valueline(data));

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + scope.height + ")")
        .call(scope.xAxis);

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(scope.yAxis)

      var obj = {
        graphName: scope.graphName,
        graphData: data
      };

      //scope.spareData.push(obj);
      scope.pushData(obj);
      //console.log(scope.spareData);
    }
  }

});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div ng-repeat="g in sampleObject">
    <my-graph graph-name="g.name" push-data="doPushData"></my-graph>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it, so i have updated the plunker link with your answer but with one change like in isolate scope replace = to & since it is a function. For some reason i am getting undefined each time when updated and then later on changed push-data="doPushData" to push-data="doPushData($value)" and scope.pushData(obj); to scope.pushData({$value:obj})